# Django and extra field in query

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I have a my query in Django that returns a list of user.

Now, for every returned user, I would to add an extra field: I need to know if the user is already friend of the current user.

I not understand if I have to use .annotate or extra() or other. I'm very confused.

I also tried this code but not work:

```
query = query.annotate(are_friends=Count(Q(user__friends=user)))
```

I obtain this error: `'Q' object has no attribute 'split'`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would want to use `extra` here.

Something along these lines:

```
User.objects.all().select_related().extra(
     select={'is_friend': "user__friends = user"})
```

`extra`'s `select` argument takes a `dict` which contains key-value pairs of columns and how to compute those columns. You may need to tinker with the `"user__friends = user"` piece a bit, depending on the exact nature of your data and models, but this should be the general approach for what you're looking to do.